# Split lines to make the code more comprehensible in notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++, text-editor

I am trying to modify a js file (It's the first time I try it) and I got something very difficult to understand for me, a mess of inline code with no breaks.

[image: screenshot]

I need it to be clean to be able to understand it, so I've been looking for a solution to break up the text into lines that represents something. I tried to split the lines where the semicolon are, but it didn't solved much.

I remember there where a program that was able to do something similar with css (I can't remember it's name).

Is it possible to do it with notepad++? if not, do you know which program can actually do it?

Thank you

Comment: No, that's minimized code.  If you need to alter that script, you should find the unminimized source version.

Comment: The pogram was a JetBrain's one, I just remembered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a code beautifier for your javascript, it is currently in 'minified' version.

Example: https://beautifier.io/

Comment: Beautiful! Now I have no excuse to try to understand a bit....

Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. You can mark ths answer as accepted if it answered your question, but most importantly: yes, please go ahead and have fun trying to understand it! We all started somewhere. Good luck